# Why does the B-52 outboard engine nacelle have a sharp change in shape?

Tags: engine-design, nacelle, b-52

The outboard engine nacelle of a B-52 appears to have a change of shape too extreme for just blending to the center-line of the engine pod. Why is the B-52 outboard engine nacelle shaped the way it is?

[image]

Comment: I am not a designer but, two closely spaced intakes competing for air need this type of nacelle to live harmoniously?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [B-52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) was built in different versions (A-H) and the engines and their installation differ between these version<sup>1</sup>.

[image]

The image in the question most likely shows the engine configuration of a B-52**H**.

The following drawings suggest that this also changed the inlet design<sup>2</sup>.

[image]

There seem to be different engine-designations depending on the application. For the B-52H, JT3Ds (TF33-P-3) were used<sup>3</sup>.

Pictures of the TF33-P-3 inlet show they are symmetrical. (While the question is focused at the outboard engine-inlet, this question can only be answered taking the other engine and the placement relative to the wing into account as well).

[image]

At the symmetry-plane the TF33-P-3 inlet-section extends further than the rest of the inlet-lip.

I would guess that there are multiple reasons and considerations which led to this design. Three of which will most likely have been:

1. Basic aerodynamic considerations like stagnation-point and pressure distribution will prefer a sharp/point nose over a flat area. Especially since the air needs to be diverted from the engine-pylon.
2. The cruise speed of the B-52H is Mach 0.91<sup>4</sup> which means the nose could also be some kind of [anti-shock-body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-shock_body) reducing [wave-drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_drag) by applying the [area-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_rule).
3. The nose between the two engines prevents aerodynamic interaction of the two engines, for example during cross-wind operation.

The negative aspects of placing two jet-engines close to each other were also discussed [in another SE-question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12365/why-do-we-never-see-high-bypass-turbofan-engines-sharing-the-same-nacelle-on-lar) with respect to commercial airliners.

---

[1]:[www.airpowerstrategy.com/](http://www.airpowerstrategy.com/2016/11/22/old-dog-new-engines/)
[2]:[http://www.afwing.com/](http://www.afwing.com/intro/b52/b-52_BUFF-15.htm)
[3]:[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_JT3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_JT3D#Specifications_(TF33-P-7))
[4]:[www.globalsecurity.org/wmd/systems/b-52.htm](https://www.globalsecurity.org/wmd/systems/b-52.htm)

Comment: I think your answer #3 is right on the money. The last thing you want is wind turbulence between two close engines, so why not close the gap and create a 'air-scoop'. That must translate to a bit more thrust.

Answer (score 15):

A lot of pictures of this intake make it quite hard to determine what is the exact geometry. But the one below is by far the best - thank you @ymb1.

[image]
http://www.af.mil/News/Photos/igphoto/2001513002/

Before, it was hard to tell exactly what's happening. In some pictures, it looked like the inboard engine was slightly further forward of the outboard engine.

But that is now shown to be incorrect. The above picture shows where the two intakes touch, the duct protrudes further forward, with a sort of "nose". This can be clearly seen from the parts of the inlet lit by the sun, and the bump in the shadow of the engine on the ground.

I would strongly expect this is to keep the airflow smooth, and reduce aerodynamic interference between the two inlets, and avoid turbulence that would cause inlet pressure distortion. This is, to avoid a difference in total pressure for each engine, between the side that is adjacent to the other engine, and the side that isn't. Uneven total pressure, or inlet distortion, can cause compressor stalls.

Answer (score 8):

> Why does the B-52 outboard engine nacelle have a sharp change in shape?

Not just the outboard, but all 8 engines on a B-52 have the same inlet design.

The original engines had a smaller fan diameter and symmetrical round inlets.

[image]

I suspect going to a larger fan diameter created flow problems which the engineers solved by modifying the inlets.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint: Add something along the line that flow with one engine of a pair out will be less disturbed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30231)

Comment: @mins I think the answer's fine now that it's been edited (though something more authoritative than "I suspect..." would be even better.)

Comment: The original engines didn't merely have a "smaller fan diameter" - they were turbojets, and, as such, had no fan at all.

Answer (score 7):

That looks like an optical illusion due to the angle to me. A photo on [this site](http://en.koreaportal.com/articles/22859/20160921/south-korea-united-states-b-52-bombers.htm) shows a more frontal view of the outboard engines, with just the equal centre division between the two engines appearing. Close-up underneath.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This inlet design was already used on the [Convair B-36 D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_B-36_Peacemaker#Addition_of_jet_propulsion), which had twin [turbojets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_J47) added on the outer wing to give it a higher top speed when penetrating enemy airspace. During cruise, only the six [piston engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_R-4360_Wasp_Major) would run and the jet engine inlets were plugged to reduce their aerodynamic drag. This plugged state is shown in the picture below (picture [source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/B-36_engines%2C_Richie.jpg)):

[image: B-36 D]

Since the B-36 was a purely subsonic design, any intention of area ruling in this design can be confidently ruled out (pun intended).

The same engine was used on the [Boeing B-47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-47_Stratojet), but here the twin intakes of the inner nacelle show no such protruding center (below, picture [source](https://b-47.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/0081.jpg)):

[image: B-47 wing and engines, with two more B-47 in the background]

Seems the Convair engineers knew something that the Boeing engineers didn't. But in Seattle they caught up eventually, and the larger airflow of the [P&W TF-33 turbofans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_JT3D) made them use the same trick from the [Boeing B-52 H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) on. All versions before used the J57 turbojet and the simple B-47 style nacelle shape (B-52 F below, picture [source](http://www.air-and-space.com/20080309%20Palmdale/BL2_0421%20B-52F%2057-0038%20right%20front%20l.jpg)):

[image: B-52 F static display]

The reason is the distorted airflow from [spillage](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29376/how-does-inlet-spillage-drag-produce-a-lip-suction-effect) if one engine of a pair has to be shut down. By pulling the divider forward in the center of the nacelle, any spillage will occur away from the running engine, ensuring symmetric intake flow there.

Comment: Are you sure about the B-47?  The inlet of the outboard engine in the inboard nacelle looks suspiciously like it does, in fact, have that sharp V-shaped notch in the intake...

Comment: @Sean: Yes. The question is about the nose between the engines, not the notch. A notch was already pioneered by the [Arado 234 V8](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12365/why-do-we-never-see-high-bypass-turbofan-engines-sharing-the-same-nacelle-on-lar/12372#12372).

Answer (score 1):

That is a perspective issue. The inlets on all B-52 models are smooth. The picture in the question makes it look like there is a sharp geometry change, but there isn't.