# Why are the engines not tucked underneath the wings of airliners?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, wing, engine

If you look at the engines of an A350 and other similar aircraft, you will see that their engines stick out ahead of the wing. Why? Why aren't they tucked under the wing?

[image]
(Source: [Airbus](https://i0.wp.com/www.airbus.com/typo3temp/pics/b670ae3ae5.png))

Comment: Also [Why do we use pylons to mount the engines on jetliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12109/1696)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bring the Center of Mass forward, and to be able to raise the jet engines, which then permits shorter and lighter landing gears.

This is what the 737 did when it moved to the bigger CFM56 engines:

Old vs new:

[image]
([Top](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Boeing_737-200_planform_view.jpg), [bottom](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Transaero_b737-400_planform_ei-cxk_arp.jpg))

---

Related: [Why do we use pylons to mount the engines on jetliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12109/why-do-we-use-pylons-to-mount-engine-on-jet-airliners)