# Why aren't plane engines mounted closer to each other or closer to the fuselage to reduce extra forces on the wings?

Tags: jet-engine

Why aren't plane engines mounted closer to each other or closer to the fuselage to reduce extra forces on the wings?

[image: A380]
[image: Cargolux 747-8]

Comment: Welcome, Mark! Please see https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23375/how-do-you-choose-engine-placement-for-under-wings-engines and https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/how-does-the-mounting-location-of-a-jet-engine-affect-aircraft-performance before asking. If the answers to both questions leave something open, refer to the existing answers so we know how to help you.

Comment: Placing the engines further out actually helps to relieve the load: in flight the wing provides lift and bends upwards, the fuselage hangs from the wings.

Comment: Also, a practical but un-ignorable requirement, if they were closer to the body, they would be closer to the ground during takeoff and taxiing, and the need a certain ground clearance. This helps avoid ground strikes, and improves performance during takeoff by providing undisturbed air to the engines. Engines often create a ground vortex in the intake which sucks up any dirt or objects from the ground. The CFM 56 engine has an oval intake because it's quite close to the ground.