# What is advantages of a wing mounted engine in comparison to tail and fuselage mounted engine?

Tags: engine-placement

What is advantages and disadvantages of wing mounted, Tail mounted and fuselage mounted engines?

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/how-does-the-mounting-location-of-a-jet-engine-affect-aircraft-performance/